# How to create a new record in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Something that should be easy, but I just can't figure out.  How do I set up the router, controller and template to deal with adding records, reporting errors from the server appropriately?

I have tried several things, the latest setting up the router so that `/users/new` loads the right template and controller:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('users', function() {
        this.route('new')
    });
});
```

The template is:

```
<form {{action 'submit' on='submit'}}>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    {{input id='name' placeholder='Enter user name' class='form-control' value=name}}
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
<div class="error">
  {{errors.content}}
</div>
```

And on submit, the controller creates a new record and saves it:

```
App.UserNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        submit: function() {
            var user = this.store.createRecord('user', {name: this.get('name')});
            user.save();
        }
    }
});
```

The template displays fine, and if I try to save with invalid data (missing name) I get a 400 error from the server reporting that "name" is required.  According to the docs, this error is attached to `model.errors`, and inspecting it in firefox shows that this is the case, but it is not shown in the template.  What am I doing wrong?

The second problem is that if I do enter a name, it isn't added to the record.  In fact, `this.get('name')` returns `undefined`.  AFAIK I'm doing everything right, but clearly there's something I'm missing.

The other concern I have is that if I mess up a few times, and click save without entering valid data, ember creates a new blank record every time.  Am I calling `createRecord` in the right place, or is there a better way on settting it up?

Answer (score 0):

First thing that attracts my attention is the controller:

It should be `UsersNewController` instead of `UserNewController` (note the s after User).

The rest looks good to me. I took your code to a jsbin and it worked: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wohob/1/edit